# Convert rows of pandas Dataframe into an iterable list of strings

Tags: python, list, pandas, intersection, iterable

Imagine I have a dataframe, df, that has 2 columns, a USER_ID and a PRODUCT they bought.

```
df
USER_ID     |     PRODUCT
1                 a
1                 b
1                 c
2                 d
2                 a
2                 k
```

I want to convert this DataFrame into a new one, df2, where each row is one user and the products are aggregated into a list of string.

```
df2
USER_ID     |     PRODUCT
1                 [a,b,c]
2                 [d,a,k]
```

Finally, I’d like to be able to find the intersection between two user’s PRODUCT lists.

I’m able to create the second dataframe, but the method I’m using results in a list that is somehow not iterable.

Specifically i do:  
    df2 = df1.groupby(‘USER_ID)[‘PRODUCT’].agg(lambda x: x.tolist())

which gives me a series that I convert back to a dataframe.

```
df2 = df2.to_frame()
```

which gives me the df2 I’m looking for but each list of products has length = 1, thus I can’t compare 1 to another to find the intersection of products.   For instance, when I execute:

```
s1 = df2.PRODUCT[df2.USER_ID == 1] 
s2 = df2.PRODUCT[df2.USER_ID == 2]

common_elements = list(set(s1).intersection(set(s2)))
common_elements
```

The result is an empty list rather than [a].  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To more directly answer your question 'what am I doing wrong?', it is hard for me to say because when I follow the exact code that you have written above, the resulting `df2` does not have a column `PRODUCT`. Have you left out some code?

Comment: @James  Use pandas crosstab...  see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
In [7]: pd.Series(np.intersect1d(df.loc[df.USER_ID == 1, 'PRODUCT'], df.loc[df.USER_ID == 2, 'PRODUCT']))
Out[7]:
0    a
dtype: object
```

or using [index.intersection()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
In [18]: (df.set_index('PRODUCT').query('USER_ID == 1').index
   ....:    .intersection(df.set_index('PRODUCT').query('USER_ID == 2').index)
   ....:    .to_series()
   ....: )
Out[18]:
PRODUCT
a    a
Name: PRODUCT, dtype: object
```

PS i wouldn't convert your `df` into `df2` as you most probably will have a lot of difficulties with this data model (i mean having lists in columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform `groupby` followed by finding intersection between the two lists as shown:

```
>>>df2 = df.groupby('USER_ID')['PRODUCT'].apply(list).reset_index()
>>>df2

   USER_ID    PRODUCT
0        1  [a, b, c]
1        2  [d, a, k]

>>>list(set(df2['PRODUCT'].loc[0]).intersection(df2['PRODUCT'].loc[1]))
['a']
```

Or in a more shorter way:

```
df2 = df.groupby('USER_ID')['PRODUCT'].apply(list)
>>>list(set(df2.loc[1]).intersection(df2.loc[2]))
['a']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df3 = pd.crosstab(df2.PRODUCT,df2.USER_ID, margins= True)
print df3[df3['All']>1]

  # USER_ID  1  2  All
   # PRODUCT           
   # a        1  1    2
   # All      3  3    6
```

My solution very simliar to @Nikil so using his.

```
df2 = df.groupby('USER_ID')['PRODUCT'].apply(list)
df2 = df2.reset_index()
print df2


#         USER_ID    PRODUCT
#    0        1  [a, b, c]
#    1        2  [d, a, k]
```

More Info on Crosstab, Its a dataframe.

```
pd.crosstab(df2.PRODUCT,df2.USER_ID, margins= True)

#    USER_ID  1  2  All
#    PRODUCT           
#    a        1  1    2
#    b        1  0    1
#    c        1  0    1
#    d        0  1    1
#    k        0  1    1
#    All      3  3    6
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a generalizable solution to find the intersection of any two users product list without the sloppy second dataframe

```
from collections import defaultdict

user1 = 1
user2 = 2
products = defaultdict(set)

for record in df.to_dict('records'):
    products[record['USER_ID']].add(record['PRODUCT'])

common_elements = products[user1].intersection(products[user2])]
print(common_elements)
```

And then if you wanted all intersections with all pairs of users

```
from itertools import combinations
common_elements = {(x,y): products[x].intersection(products[y]) for x,y in combinations(products.keys(),2)}
```